# Create series of time data in R

Tags: r, time, schedule

If I have data like this:

```
x y Z Frequency(minutes) start_time End_time
1 2 1    7                00:06:00   06:21:00
```

and I want to convert it to this format,  how to do it in R?

```
x y Z Frequency(minutes) start_time End_time  New_time
1 2 1      7             06:00:00   06:21:00  06:07:00
1 2 1      7             06:00:00   06:21:00  06:14:00
1 2 1      7             06:00:00   06:21:00  06:21:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
#  First pull in data
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "
                 x y z frequency_min start_time end_time
1 2 1    7                06:00:00   06:21:00") %>%

  # Reformat timestamps
  mutate(start_time2 = lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(Sys.Date(), start_time)),
         end_time2 = lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(Sys.Date(), end_time))) %>%

  # Figure out how many rows needed of each
  mutate(copies = (end_time2 - start_time2) / 
           lubridate::dminutes(1) / frequency_min) %>%

  # Make this many copies
  uncount(copies, .id = "copy_id") %>%

  # Add requested 'new_time' column
  mutate(new_time = start_time2 + frequency_min * copy_id * dminutes(1))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get error when I run the code. the error says that Error in rep(seq_nrow(data), w) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: Hmm. Can you identify which step is producing that error? Try taking out the `%>%` one by one from the top (and then putting back).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry. It was my fault there are some NA data in my files. Now. it works. Thanks again!